# remove last line with explode function

Tags: php, string, explode

I have this text stored in a variable:

> shared by: mindfuq on: Sunday, June 12, 2011 Buried Prey by John Sandford Buried PreyIn Buried Prey, this latest John Sandford drama features his favorite main character,policeman "hunter" of bad guys, Lucas Davenport, who revisits a cold case from his past.Victims of a case he had worked on early in his career are discover
>   Share With Friends: | | Art - Literature Stories, RSS Feeds and Widgets via Feedzilla.

I want to remove the last line of this text.  How can I do this with `explode`?  `str_replace` isn't working for me.

Comment: Why do you want to do it with `explode()`?

Comment: BTW, where does this parse XML?

Comment: You should consider marking deceze's or my answer correct if either of them worked for you.

Answer (score 11):

```
$string = substr($string, 0, strrpos($string, "\n"));
```

If you absolutely want to use `explode`:

```
$string = join("\n", array_slice(explode("\n", $string), 0, -1));
```

Both methods assume that there's no trailing `"\n"` after the last line, see @binaryLV's comment.

Comment: I would replace `$string` with `rtrim($string)` in `strpos()` call. That way, it would not matter if there is any trailing `\n`. There might be some problems with `\r\n` though, so it might be worth adding `$string = str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $string)` before calling `substr()`.

Comment: To be platform independent, I'd use PHP_EOL rather than str_replace.

Answer (score 0):

If the content contains no other line breaks, use `strstr()`:

```
$line = strstr(trim($text), "\n", true); // last arg true, to return before needle
```

If there will be multiple line breaks, and you want to programmatically remove lines:

```
$lines = explode("\n", trim($text));
unset($lines[count($lines) - 1]); // removes last line
```